# Pausing after process completion in the console from a C# WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, process, console

I'm writing a WinForms application that runs a process in a new console window when a user clicks a button.  Is there any way to get the console window to pause - waiting for a keypress - before the process exits, to allow the user to view the output onto the console?  The following code runs the process in a console window, but the window disappears immediately after execution finishes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Process.Start(@"ffmpeg.exe", "--help");
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?  That doesn't keep the console window open until there's a keypress, after the process finishes.

Comment: I don't have that program on my machine, but when I do this with cmd.exe, the console window already stays open. If it's something about this program, maybe open a process to cmd.exe and then give the command for ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to end up doing was invoking a `.bat` script that took parameters from the WinForms app to behave how I wanted, and the script finished with a `@PAUSE` to wait for a keypress.  Don't think there's another way to do it, annoyingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cmd like so (/k makes it not close the window)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", "/k ffmpeg.exe --help");
}
```

Comment: That works quite well but instead of 'press a key to continue' before closing the window, it enters an interactive command prompt.